# Scale car wrap template to actual size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, scale, template

I have an Adobe AI template of a 2017 Ford F250 that is designed at 1:20 scale that I would like to scale up to its actual size. Is there a way I could scale the entire template so that it’s size matches the exact size of the vehicle?

Comment: Why do you want to scale it to actual size?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. Guess it would depend upon the vehicle. Illustrator's maximum artboard size is 227" (roughly 18 feet), which may be too small for some vehicle sizes.

Merely Select All then scale.

Be aware though, working that large in AI can cause it to be terribly slow depending on the amount of detail you add to the artwork.

Most people work at 50% or even 25% of actual size if not smaller, especially in a vector application where size doesn't matter.